# How to get a total number of consecutive observations in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
START_DATE  ITEM_ID SALE_PRICE
28-12-14    914602  0
04-01-15    914602  0
11-01-15    914602  0
18-01-15    914602  0
25-01-15    914602  2
01-02-15    914602  0
08-02-15    914602  0
15-02-15    914602  2
22-02-15    914602  2
01-03-15    914602  2
08-03-15    914602  0
15-03-15    914602  2
22-03-15    914602  2
29-03-15    914602  2
05-04-15    914602  2
12-04-15    914602  2
19-04-15    914602  2
```

I want to get total number of consecutive sale prices when there is a change in sale price
Output required is:

```
START_DATE  ITEM_ID SALE_PRICE  No_of_times
28-12-14    914602  0   4
25-01-15    914602  2   1
01-02-15    914602  0   2
15-02-15    914602  2   3
08-03-15    914602  0   1
15-03-15    914602  2   6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
ind<-which(c(TRUE,df$SALE_PRICE[-1]!=df$SALE_PRICE[-nrow(df)]))
cbind(df[ind,],No_of_items=diff(c(ind,nrow(df)+1)))
#   START_DATE ITEM_ID SALE_PRICE No_of_items
#1    28-12-14  914602          0           4
#5    25-01-15  914602          2           1
#6    01-02-15  914602          0           2
#8    15-02-15  914602          2           3
#11   08-03-15  914602          0           1
#12   15-03-15  914602          2           6
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possibility with "data.table". You may need to adjust according to what your actual grouping variable/variables are. If you want to change the column order, use `setcolorder` at the end, and you can drop the `rid` column with `rid := NULL` if required.

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, rid := rleid(SALE_PRICE)][
  , c(TIMES = .N[1], lapply(.SD, head, 1)), by = rid]
#    rid TIMES START_DATE ITEM_ID SALE_PRICE
# 1:   1     4   28-12-14  914602          0
# 2:   2     1   25-01-15  914602          2
# 3:   3     2   01-02-15  914602          0
# 4:   4     3   15-02-15  914602          2
# 5:   5     1   08-03-15  914602          0
# 6:   6     6   15-03-15  914602          2
```

---

In base R, you can simply use `rle`:

```
x <- rle(mydf$SALE_PRICE)
cbind(mydf[cumsum(c(1, x$lengths[-length(x$lengths)])), ], TIMES = x$lengths)
##    START_DATE ITEM_ID SALE_PRICE TIMES
## 1    28-12-14  914602          0     4
## 5    25-01-15  914602          2     1
## 6    01-02-15  914602          0     2
## 8    15-02-15  914602          2     3
## 11   08-03-15  914602          0     1
## 12   15-03-15  914602          2     6
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use function `rleid` function of package `data.table` to create a grouping id for consecutive identical value.

So, using `data.table` I would do :

```
DT <- fread("START_DATE  ITEM_ID SALE_PRICE
28-12-14    914602  0
04-01-15    914602  0
11-01-15    914602  0
18-01-15    914602  0
25-01-15    914602  2
01-02-15    914602  0
08-02-15    914602  0
15-02-15    914602  2
22-02-15    914602  2
01-03-15    914602  2
08-03-15    914602  0
15-03-15    914602  2
22-03-15    914602  2
29-03-15    914602  2
05-04-15    914602  2
12-04-15    914602  2
19-04-15    914602  2")

DT[, No_of_time := length(ITEM_ID), by = rleid(SALE_PRICE)]
unique(DT, by = "No_of_time")
#>    START_DATE ITEM_ID SALE_PRICE No_of_time
#> 1:   28-12-14  914602          0          4
#> 2:   25-01-15  914602          2          1
#> 3:   01-02-15  914602          0          2
#> 4:   15-02-15  914602          2          3
#> 5:   15-03-15  914602          2          6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(gr=cumsum(SALE_PRICE!= lag(SALE_PRICE, default=0))) %>%
  mutate(No_of_times=n()) %>% 
  slice(1L)  %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr)
#    START_DATE ITEM_ID SALE_PRICE No_of_times
#       (chr)   (int)      (int)       (int)
#1   28-12-14  914602          0           4
#2   25-01-15  914602          2           1
#3   01-02-15  914602          0           2
#4   15-02-15  914602          2           3
#5   08-03-15  914602          0           1
#6   15-03-15  914602          2           6
```